# Wagtail permission for different user pass

Tags: python, django, wagtail

in my wagtail app, I have a model that I want to only allow certain types of users to view that model. In django I would just inherit UserPassesTestMixin. In wagtail, I will allow it based on a session data. If request.session.dados_usuarios.bu == 'Corporate KO', he will be able to view the page. I'm new to wagtail, is it possible to do this?

In django I would do it like this

```
class SomeView(UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
     ...

     def test_func(self):
         return request.session.dados_usuario.bu == 'Corporate KO'
```

My model in wagtail app

```
class IframePage(Page):
    iframe_url = models.URLField()

    fabricantes_com_acesso = ParentalManyToManyField(
            Fabricante,
            blank=True,
            verbose_name="Fabricas com Acesso"
        )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('iframe_url'),
                FieldPanel('fabricantes_com_acesso'),
            ], 
            
        heading="Informações Principais"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail has [page privacy settings](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/privacy.html) but they are set on sections of the page tree rather than by page type. The easiest option would be if all your IframePages were in the same section of the page tree. Then you can set a page privacy setting on the parent page and all of the subpages will inherit it.

If you really need this to work per page type anywhere in the page tree, you could [add a hook](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#aft) to set the page privacy setting on all IframePages when they are created.